# When select value from combo, highlight that record in Access subform datasheet

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have an Access form with a combobox and a subform on it.  The subform is in datasheet mode (the way I want it).  What I'm trying to do is make a sort of search function.  When something is selected from the combobox, I want the subform's datasheet to scroll to and highlight the matching record.

I do not want to filter the subform (i.e. remove all non-matching records).

Can anyone give me some guidance on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Combo0_AfterUpdate():
    With Me.Child0.Form.Recordset
        .FindFirst "ID_Field=" & Me.Combo0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: -Perfect!  Now, how can I make a button send the subform to its Add Entry mode?  Where I can add a new record onto the bottom of the existing ones?

Comment: Best if you ask that as a new question, I think.

Comment: First off, there is no reason to set a recordset since there's one that already exists for the purpose of navigation, the form's RecordsetClone. That's more appropriate, seems to me. But if you're going to set that recordset variable, you should clear it.

Comment: I edited my answer so that I am no longer setting a separate Recordset.  However, RecordsetClone will not work in this case because the OP wants the update to be visible in the UI.  You generally use the RecordsetClone when you want to browse through the form's Recordset without affecting the user interface.