# How to add new record to subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I recently got help on [When select value from combo, highlight that record in Access subform datasheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6795377/456532) and now I'm trying to do a related task.

How can I make the subform give me a new row for data entry from a button on the main form?

Tried the method found here with no luck: http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=26537

EDIT: Not sure if it matters, but the table my subform is supposed to update is a linked table to SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please first make sure your recordsource is updateable by opening the table or query in which your subform recordsource is based, and ensure that you can edit and add new records.  If not, then it's possible that your SQL Server linked table is missing a unique indentifier.  To create one, simply delete the linked table, and relink it.  Upon relinking, MS Access should prompt you to specify a unique index (may take more than one field to make it truly unique).  Then try again.

Comment: -You got it!  My SQL table does have a primary key, and I can edit the table from Access, but my subform's datasource was a query that did not include the primary key.  I added that key and now everything works!  You're the man!

Answer (score 1):

If the subform datasheet is editable and with AllowAdditions turned on, it should already give you the * button to add a new row.

If it doesn't, then you need to check the datasheet's properties and change them to match what you're actually seeking.

Comment: -The AllowAdditions property is set like that.

Comment: -AllowAddition is set to True.  I do not get the * (asterisk) to add new items.

Comment: If you edit the Recordsource of your subform does it have the asterisk button for adding new records? If not, you need to determine what about your SQL is preventing adding new records. Post the SQL of the subform...

Answer (score 0):

it has been a while since I used Access. Doesn't the RecordSource property of the subform give you the underlying table or query. If the source is editable, you should be able to add a record then Requery or Refresh the subform.

Comment: It's a little more automatic if you have Linked Master and Child Fields filled out.

Answer (score 0):

For those who need just to add a new record to sub form: just set focus from main form to subform. Then use DoCmd to add new record:

```
Forms![MainFormName]![SubFormName].SetFocus
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```

Comment: I can use this, but I'm not quite clear what procedure I would put it in.  Also, would it add a new record every time the subform gets the focus?